# Does the C++ standard allow a template constructor for a non-template class?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I want to create a class with a template constructor:

```
class foo
{
    template <class T> foo(T var) {}
};
```

This compiles in VS2008, but I have no idea if it is a non-standard extension, or if the C++ standard allows it.

Comment: I've found, at least in terms of straight C++, MS respects the standard and doesn't generally break from it for extensions the way some do.

Comment: It is allowed, and comes in quite handy sometimes. There is no reason it shouldn't compile. The constructor is still a function, and as such can be template-based. There is a restriction to constructors however. They cannot be invoked with *explicit* template parameters; they *must* be deducible from the argument list. I.e. `template <class T> foo() { T something; ...}` will not work.

Comment: @BobbyDigital Seriously? Where's tow-phase name lookup in templates? The preprocessor is downright broken. Binding temporaries to mutable references is just a warning (by default). Where're auto-generated move ctors/assignment ops? MSVC is one of the less conformant compilers.

Comment: "Binding temporaries to mutable references is just a warning (by default)" -- for what it's worth, this part is standard-conforming. A warning is sufficient to diagnose an ill-formed program, there is no requirement that conforming compilers must reject it.

Comment: @Angew: Yes seriously, especially since it seems you're missing the point. OK, you've named things that are *non-standard* compliant which are *in* the standard; right? How are these then *extensions* as op was referring to? They were curious if this was some *extension* to the standard provided by MS, like VLAs available in other compilers, which allows them to do the above. Doesn't appear to be the same thing, but thanks for the info.

Comment: @BobbyDigital I was primarily reacting to "MS generally respects the standard," which it really does not that well. Extensions can be turned off, bugs can't. And `T&` temporaries are an extension, anyway. But you do have a point that MSVC has less extensions than e.g. GCC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [temp.mem]:

> A template can be declared within a class or class template; such a
>   template is called a member template.

Constructors are members and it isn't explicitly disallowed to make them templates.

For example, `std::shared_ptr` has many [template constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).